# GAS Can I search down instead of across an array using indexOf()

Tags: google-apps-script, indexof

I have a table in a sheet which acts like a database. A4 holds some maths to tally up the number of entries in the table. It takes ages searching through it using nested for loops, so I wondered if I could put all of the data into an array and then use indexOf() to find a match for a userpermit combination in column 12. It fails (I get -1 back) as it seems the search only works on a one-dimensional array and that seems to be across, not down. I have played with code and searched for comments but to no avail. Any idea. Here is some code I have used so far. Is there any way I can indexOf down rather than across to find the userpermit.

```
//  get the data
var spreadsheet            = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SHEETURL);
var permitssheet           = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('permits');
var int_uptally            = permitssheet.getRange("A4").getValue();
var ar_permitsdatablock    = permitssheet.getRange(4,12,int_uptally,1).getValues();

//  prepare the response
codestring = "Add permit - checking for an existing permit - "; 

//  do the search
var key = e.parameter.selecteduseremail + "~" + e.parameter.selectedoption;
var permitkeyfound  = ar_permitsdatablock[1].indexOf(key);

//  send the result back
    codestring = codestring + "Block [0]";
    codestring = codestring + ar_permitsdatablock[0];
    codestring = codestring + "<br>"; 
    codestring = codestring + "Block [1]";
    codestring = codestring + ar_permitsdatablock[1];
    codestring = codestring + "<br>"; 
    codestring = codestring + key;
    codestring = codestring + " - key found at = "; 
    codestring = codestring + permitkeyfound;
    codestring = codestring + "<br>";
```

Comment: Use `.findIndex` instead

Comment: Are you able to share dummy data for the community to replicate? It does not have to be exactly your data if it contains sensitive information. This is just so we can visualize and replicate what you have as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: For future reference, [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: nr_permits<br>
maths added updated hit ID ID hit<br>
int_uptally dt_permitadded dt_permitupdated dt_permitlastused tx_optioncode tx_useremail dt_userlasthit tx_optiontype tx_optionname tx_username tx_permitstatus tx_permit_key_em_oc<br>
12r 2023/12/10 09:57:27 2023/12/10 09:57:27 2024/01/11 20:13:40 viewspace email1.com 2024/03/28 08:55:35 view View Space Kevin Jory yes email1.com~viewspace<br>
11 2023/12/10 09:57:27 2023/12/10 09:57:27 2024/01/11 20:13:40 addpermit email1.com 2024/03/28 08:55:35 action Add Permit Kevin Jory yes email1.com~addpermit<br>

Comment: I have changed the code above to get the whole range from A4 to column L (12) and down to the end as tasalyed- `var ar_permitsdatablock    = permitssheet.getRange(4,1,int_uptally,12).getValues();`Also tried this - `var permitkeyfound  = ar_permitsdatablock.findIndex(key);` but no joy. There seems to be no way to search into a 2D array.

Comment: Given hints in here and the link supplied to similar questions, I now have an approximation to the solution. `var flatarray = ar_permitsdatablock.flat(2);` flattens the array to one dimension and  `var permitkeyfound  = flatarray.indexOf(key);` then finds the key successfully. Not sure yet what the reply number means (35 in this case) but my need is to see if it's there or not so -1 or not -1 is good enough. Thanks for the hints.